# EOF within quoted string...then more columns than column names

Tags: r, csv, eof, read.csv

I am trying to import data from a CSV file and am having the typical "EOF within quoted string" problem. As many other posts suggested, I set quote as follows:

```
orionwebdata <- read.csv("OrionWebData.csv", quote = "")
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
more columns than column names
```

I am guessing that by removing quotes, some commas in quotes are read and the lines are split where they are not supposed to be split. Other posts suggested using fread:

```
orionwebdata <- fread("OrionWebData.csv", quote = "")
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fread("OrionWebData.csv", quote = "") :
  Detected 401 column names but the data has 400 columns. Filling rows automatically. Set fill=TRUE explicitly to avoid this warning.
2: In fread("OrionWebData.csv", quote = "") :
  Stopped early on line 7. Expected 401 fields but found 411. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<"2019","0141900001024020","01","01","C","000","   "," ","   ","   "," ","   ","   "," ","   ","0162168","0000000","0000000","00162168","003.72","0000","    ","    ","  ","00"," ","0","0"," ","  ","      ","0000000"," "," ","       ","       "," "," "," ","0","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","  ","  ","  ","  ","     ","   ","    ","
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: use the verbose=TRUE option to (hopefully) get more helpful output from fread

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like verbose doesn't change the output.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason if I open this in Excel, save it as a tab delimited file, then open in R with:

```
orionwebdata <- read.delim("OrionWebData_tab.txt", sep = "\t")
```

then it works. I  guess the comma delimiter was problematic for some reason, whereas the computer is able to correctly interpret tabs, though I am not sure why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's definitely comma-separated. I got that error using read.table on a slightly weirdly formatted tab-separated file when I hadn't explicitly said `'sep = '\t'` so I think because of the weirdness it was guessing the separator wrong - you could try using read.csv with sep = ',' written explicitly, or read.table with different sep values.

Comment: It looks like it is a CSV, it's saved as .csv, and when I open it in Notepad it's clear each field is separated by commas. It opens fine in Excel as a CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything either.